# Untracked Working Tree .gitignore - no luck with clean -f or git rm - How to reset the all thing?

Tags: git, gitignore

Each time the remote is Pulling changes into Dev [Hub's post-update hook],

I'm getting:

> error: Untracked working tree file 'somepath/here/.gitignore' would be
>   overwritten by merge.  Aborting

If I do `git status` on the **remote** I get:

```
#On branch dev nothing to commit
(working directory clean)
```

I understand that the file is there, I've stupidly create it directly on the remote machine (without doing push);

I understand git refuses to merge it.

Updated:

I've tried on the remote machine do:

```
git rm .gitignore
```

but I got:

```
fatal: pathspec 'path/.gitignore' did not match any files
```

I've tried on the remote machine do:

```
git clean -f
```

Did nothing and the same `Untracked working tree file` error appears.

I've run:

```
git clean -f -d -x
```

It removed that file and folders untracked on the remote.

Update:
I've change no matter what file to trigger the push option.
When pushed, the bare detected changes and has made them.

For some reason yet not clear, a .css file (and perhaps more things) where not taken on that refresh on the remote server, so I change no matter what on that css just to trigger the push, and again, all was clear.

This is obviously the way we SHOULDN'T do it. It apparently is ok. But I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: Next time if you see `Untracked working tree` error and you don't want the changes at all, just `rm` the files (`rm`, not `git rm`). Per the output, your changes are in an untracked file. That's why `git rm` fails: git cannot remove an untracked file from the index.

Comment: @Christopher thanks a lot for taking your time reading my "struggle" here. By "don't want the changes at all" what do you mean ? I had this file on the remote repo not tracked by the working tree, because of that, the remove repo was refusing to pull from the remote `bare` repo to the remote `dev` repo. Locally all was apparently nice, so I though: "I could well remove that .gitignore remotely" because I have it locally, and sooner or later, I will push it again, no "nothing is lost" - in this sense, I didn't NEED the changes at all (at least, so I thought).

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. If your remote again gets polluted with an untracked file, throws this error, and you are 100% confident you don't need the remote's untracked version (it sounds like this describes your situation), then `ssh` over to the remote and `rm` the file. You were about 98% of the way to this solution, you were just using `git rm` on the remote instead of `rm`. The former works on _tracked_ files in git's index. The latter is what you want when removing untracked files.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, a simple `rm` is enough.

But you also have the option of `git reset --hard`, *in addition* of `git clean -f -d -x`.
That is what [`git clean` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#git-clean--x) suggests "to create a pristine working directory".